# laravel php 7 convert type with db query

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, php-7

I was used Laravel 5.4 with PHP 5.6,
Then I upgrade PHP to PHP 7.1, And something weird happens,

All of my DB::query result object convert to String, For example I fetch **phone_number** of users and convert it to **json**, In PHP 5.6 **phone_number** was **interger** in json, but now(PHP 7.1) **phone_number** is **String** in json output,

What is the problem?

Comment: could you show a bit of code somewhere so we can try to help you out ?

Comment: @Unex It's very simple, I fetch data with laravel DB and convert it to json

Comment: Well since the json_decode & json_decode works the same way for me, in both version i do not think this is completely related to php 7.1. You can check here : https://3v4l.org/74bbE. Maybe the issue is with you php-postgres or php-mysql, but i do not think this is related to php 7.1 directly